# Downloading jpg image from url with URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, urlsession

I'm trying to download an image from a url in swift. This is the image [url](https://media.wired.com/photos/5f2d7c2191d87e6680b80936/16:9/w_2400,h_1350,c_limit/Science_climatedesk_453801484.jpg) I'm trying to download, and I'm expecting it to download it to On my iPhone > testExampleApplication in the application's documents directory, but when I click the button, nothing downloads. Here's my code:

```
Button("Download logo image") {
      let imageUrlStr = "https://media.wired.com/photos/5f2d7c2191d87e6680b80936/16:9/w_2400,h_1350,c_limit/Science_climatedesk_453801484.jpg".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageUrlStr)!), completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        print("download details 1: \(data)")
        print("download details 2: \(response)")
        print("download details 3: \(error)")
      })
      // Start the download.
      task.resume()
}
```

The Content-type in the 2nd print is image/jpeg and the error print is nil.

Am I doing something wrong in my downloading code?

Comment: Your title says `png` and then you refer to a `jpg` image. But, that's probably irrelevant anyway because the image type is unlikely to matter compared to the more important questions: What are you expecting to happen exactly? It looks like your current code is running. Are you trying to save it to the application's documents directory? Or to the photo library?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that, I've just updated the title. So with you're question, I'm trying to save it in the application's documents directory, not the photo library. I'll actually go ahead and also put that in my question.

Comment: You can use **Kingfisher** for getting image from url.

Comment: @Imran0001 Can you provide an answer or an example on how to use this library to download images?

Comment: @Amy, I am just writing.

Comment: Your code is supposed to work. Doesn't  `download details 1` show the number of bytes?

Comment: @vadian Yes download details 1 shows the number of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's a good idea to do asynchronous tasks like this in a `ObservableObject` rather than the `View` itself.

You're already doing the downloading -- all you need to do now is save the data:

```
class Downloader : ObservableObject {
    func downloadImage() {
        let imageUrlStr = "https://media.wired.com/photos/5f2d7c2191d87e6680b80936/16:9/w_2400,h_1350,c_limit/Science_climatedesk_453801484.jpg".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
              let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageUrlStr)!), completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
                
                  guard let data = data else {
                      print("No image data")
                      return
                  }
                  
                  do {
                      try data.write(to: self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image.jpg"))
                      print("Image saved to: ",self.getDocumentsDirectory())
                  } catch {
                      print(error)
                  }
                  
              })
              // Start the download.
              task.resume()
    }
    
    private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var downloader = Downloader()
    
    var body : some View {
        Button("Download") {
            downloader.downloadImage()
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this in the simulator, you can see the output to the console with the location of the directory. If you open that in Finder, you'll see your image has been saved there.

Note that to see the directory and file in the Files app, you'll need to make sure that you've set `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `YES` in your `Info.plist`

Answer (score -2):

Firstly import **Kingfisher** as-

```
pod 'Kingfisher'
```

Then import it in your class as -

```
import Kingfisher
```

After that add a temporary UIImageView

```
let imgView = UIImageView()
imgView.kf.setImage(with: yourImageURL)

if let finalImage = imgView.image {
    // finalImage is your image
}
```